# Python requests returning 500 error despite copying HTTP headers

Tags: python, python-requests

A code of mine is now throwing 500 errors (where it didn't before) at a step where I am required to communicate with the following website: http://metagenomics.iiserb.ac.in/mp3/application.php

I am receiving 500 errors when making GET or POST requests, however it works fine in the browser which tells me there's an error with the HTTP headers. When I replicate the headers I see on Chrome as follows, I still get the errors:

```
payload = {"program": "metabin", "method": "blast", "filetype": "blastresult", "samplefile": "blast", "bitscore": "-0.2", "binsize": "30", "email": "", "submit": "Submit"}
headers = {"Origin": "http://metagenomics.iiserb.ac.in", "Referer": "http://metagenomics.iiserb.ac.in/mp3/application.php", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36", "X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id": "A6A0EFE8F8ECE2562D4EDF2B00589DC1"}
requests.post("http://metagenomics.iiserb.ac.in/mp3/submitjob.php", files=payload, headers=headers)
```

Am I incorrectly copying the HTTP headers? Or is there another step I am missing?

Thanks,
Josh.

Comment: The 500 error comes from the server. Requests is just telling you what it gets from the server. Why are you using `files=payload` when the payload is just a dictionary of strings? Try another keyword in your post method. `json=` or `data=`

Comment: @HåkenLid Thanks for your response :) Sorry I should have stated that I tried json and data as well but they have returned 500 errors. I had chosen files as I will be uploading a file as well.

As it's a 500 error I know it's a server side error but as it works fine in the browser I have assumed it's an error with my request, such as a header it is expecting but isn't there.

Comment: You can inspect the actual request headers from the response object. `response = requests.post(...); print(response.request.headers)`. However a `500` error means that your server has a bug. It's not a normal response. If your post request is incorrect/malformed, the proper (by convention / standard) response from the server would be in the 400 range.

Comment: @HåkenLid The server belongs to another team, but I appreciate the response may be incorrect in this circumstance. What is confusing me is why it is working fine in browser but not by Python Requests. I.e. http://metagenomics.iiserb.ac.in/mp3/index.php works fine on the browser, but a GET request results in a response 500

Answer (score 0):

```
payload = {"program": "metabin",
           "method": "blast",
           "filetype": "blastresult",
           "samplefile": "blast",
           "bitscore": "-0.2",
           "binsize": "30",
           "email": "",
           "submit": "Submit"}

headers = {"Origin": "http://metagenomics.iiserb.ac.in",
           "Referer": "http://metagenomics.iiserb.ac.in/mp3/application.php",
           "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36",
           "X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id": "A6A0EFE8F8ECE2562D4EDF2B00589DC1"}

requests.post("http://metagenomics.iiserb.ac.in/mp3/submitjob.php", data=payload, headers=headers)
```

But I still don't see the "file", as you don't open it binary, to send a file through request post method to a server you should make something similar (these will be just example params!)

```
data = {'csrf-token' : '214214cqwt21',
        'title'      :  'Blue sky'}
files = {'file-data' : open("mypicture.jpg", "rb")}

session.post("http://targeturl.com", data = data, files = files)
```